Sanitizing IOwinContext Request Body
I Write a middleware using C# and the idea is to take the post requests and sanitize html and script tags. I tried to use HTMLSanitizer from Nuget, but the tags aren't removed. How can i do this? Below is my code:
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
        string localPath = context.Request.Uri.LocalPath;                  

        if(!whiteList.Contains(localPath) && context.Request.Method.ToLower() == "post")
        { 
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var raw = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                var requestBody = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(raw);
                var sanitiser = new HtmlSanitizer();
                var sanitised = sanitiser.Sanitize(requestBody);



                if(raw != sanitised)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sanitised);
                    context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                }

            }

            context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        await Next.Invoke(context);
       
    }

